# Massive performance fluctuations with MS SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl, fme

I have an ETL job (extract, transform, load, developed with Safe FME 2018) and running against MS SQL Server 2016. This job processes only regular data (no spatial data): The data is extracted from several MS SQL Server tables, transformed with FME and loaded back to the database into several other tables. The ETL job is split into 5 subjobs: Subjobs 1 to 4 write their results into several tables, the 5th subjob collects all written data and writes it into another database.

This job executes many SQL statements in sequence, some of them quite complex and long-running (5-10 minutes).

If I run this process several times in a row, using exactly the same dataset (around 20,000 records to process), the result is very confusing:

- run 1 and 2 last about 8 min, as expected
- run 3 never comes to an end: The process is stuck in the first SQL and hangs forever.
- If I kill this third run and execute run 4 and 5, everything is fine again, we are down to 8min.
- run 6 hangs again
- and so on...

I have no idea where to go further with my error analysis. In my opinion, all SQL statements should be working fine. Is there any magic going on on MS SQL Server, like optimising or caching queries or anything, blocking or locking my queries? Any hints?

Regards, Tobias

Comment: It could be do to blocking but no one here can tell you without monitoring your server. Consider configuring the blocked process report threshold and capturing the event in a [trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/blocked-process-report-event-class).

Comment: Consider using a tool such as WhoIsActive http://whoisactive.com/ by Adam Machanic, this will tell you what is waiting and what it's waiting on.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. My process seems not to be blocked, at least I couldn't find a hint for that. But with sp_who I've found that my process is in "runnable" status. But this confuses me again: It's written "runnable: The session's task is in the runnable queue of a scheduler while waiting to get a time quantum." But what's the reason for this status?

Comment: Run sp_who a few more times, is it constantly in the runnable state?  If so, then it's waiting for cpu resource, check sys.dm_os_schedulers

Comment: If it's only runnable, compare the plans of the slow and faster runs to see if different.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I've fired sp_who and sp_who2 again and again during run 1 and 2, and it's interesting: For the same. SPID I see several lines, mostly with status SUSPENDED, but some of them with status RUNNABLE. What happens here?